# jQuery doesn't react on click on added class

Tags: jquery, click, addclass, removeclass

I have a rather simple script where I want a div to disappear when jQuery loads, add an "trigger" element on which I can click so that the div appears again. Then the class of the "trigger" is changed and when I click that again, the div should disappear again.. unfortunately the script works fine just until the "trigger" class is changed, if I click it again nothing happens.

**QUESTION SOLVED**

Here is the **working** JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($('#Bestellungen #Offene .products')) {
    $('#Bestellungen #Offene .products').hide();
    $('#Bestellungen #Offene .products').before('<div class="trigger"></div>');
    $('#Bestellungen #Offene').on('click', '.trigger', function () {
        $(this).addClass('minus').next().show();
    });
    $('#Bestellungen #Offene').on('click', '.trigger.minus', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('minus').next().hide();
    });
}
```

});

And here the HTML:

```
<div id="Bestellungen">
<div id="Offene">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="products">blablabla</div>
            <td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case of, Dynamically added `class` element you need delegate event. Because, element with dynamic `class` or `id` treated as `dynamic` element with that `class` or `id`.

As you're adding the class `minus` to `.trigger` later,so, `.trigger.minus` treating as dynamic element.

So try:

```
$('#Bestellungen #Offene').on('click', '.trigger.minus', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('minus').next().hide();
});
```

In order to implement a delegate event you need to use ***[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)*** method of jQuery like above.

#### Note

Syntax of `.on()` for delegate event is:

```
$(StaticParentElement).on(eventName, target, handlerFunction);
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your quick reply!! I also had to change the click event before the second one to the .on() method, but now it works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `on` attachment process.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($('#Bestellungen #Offene .products')) {
    $('#Bestellungen #Offene .products').hide();
    $('#Bestellungen #Offene .products').before('<div class="trigger"></div>');
    $('#Bestellungen #Offene').on('click', '.trigger:not(.minus)', function () {
        $(this).addClass('minus').next().show();
    });

    /* This is the section that doesn't work */
    $('#Bestellungen #Offene').on('click',  '.trigger.minus', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('minus').next().hide();
    });
}
```

Also, you'll need to filter out elements that have the `.minus` class from the first event handler so that they aren't executed when you click on items with the `.minus` class.

Alternatively, you could write the code like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($('#Bestellungen #Offene .products')) {
    $('#Bestellungen #Offene .products').hide();
    $('#Bestellungen #Offene .products').before('<div class="trigger"></div>');
    $('#Bestellungen #Offene .trigger').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('minus').next().toggle();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Especially your alternative answer is very good, because it's less code than my previous solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because you're not attaching the 'minus' handler to the element since it doesn't have the class at the time you try to bind it.
you can use on to attach events to parent elements and then have a selector matching your target, or you can also use a single handler for both cases:

```
$('#Bestellungen #Offene .trigger').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('minus').next().toggle($(this).hasClass('minus'));
});
```

This works because toggle function accepts a boolean parameter indicating whether to show or hide the elements.